# How to turn off automatic indentation after closing braces

Tags: vim

My vim autoindent a line when I close a brace, I want to get rid of this.
I tried :

- set nocindent
- set noautoindent
- set nosmartindent

None of them works.

What I'm observing :
lets say I have this text :

```
        - a
        - b
        - c
```

I want to add `\color{A}` in front of the letter "a". This is the result after typing `\color{A}`:

```
                - \color{A}a
        - b
        - c
```

How can I prevent that line from getting indented?

Comment: What's the filetype? If you type `:set ft?` what does Vim tell you about it? Do you have an indentexpr set? Check it with `:set indentexpr?`.